# CMake error "Automatic include detection via cmake could not be executed. See log for details."

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt, googletest

I am trying to use the google test framework with my current eclipse project, which builds using CDT builder with cmake4eclipse 3.0.3. For including the googletest package, I used the following to download it as an external project within my project. The following is my *CMakeLists.txt.in* file:

```
project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           main
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

And this is the *CMakeLists.txt* in which I actually build the google test and include it for my tests:

```
project(Myproject)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

##################### build google test #####################

# Download and unpack googletest at configure time
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.in googletest-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-download )
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for googletest failed: ${result}")
endif()

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Add googletest directly to our build. This defines
# the gtest and gtest_main targets.
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build)
                 #EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# The gtest/gtest_main targets carry header search path
# dependencies automatically when using CMake 2.8.11 or
# later. Otherwise we have to add them here ourselves.
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.11)
  include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()

#######################################################################################

# Some irrelevant code here ...

#######################################################################################

############## Build my test ###################
add_executable(unit_test src/SomeUnitTest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(unit_test gtest gtest_main)

add_test(NAME big_test COMMAND unit_test)
```

My output is:

```
[cmake]: -- Configuring done
[cmake]: -- Generating done
[cmake]: -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Me/eclipse-workspace/Myproject/intermediate/cmake/AXCF2152,22.3.0.20/Release/googletest-download
[cmake]: [ 11%] [34m[1mPerforming update step for 'googletest'[0m
[cmake]: Current branch main is up to date.
[cmake]: [ 22%] [34m[1mNo configure step for 'googletest'[0m
[cmake]: [ 33%] [34m[1mNo build step for 'googletest'[0m
[cmake]: [ 44%] [34m[1mNo install step for 'googletest'[0m

Automatic include detection via cmake could not be executed. See log for details.
Successfully generated all files with the 'code' generator for C:\Users\Me\eclipse-workspace\Myproject.
```

I am using a Windows machine and as I mentioned above my eclipse is using the CDT builder with cmake4eclipse 3.0.3. When I query the cmake version it tells me it is 3.13.1. I do have another cmake version 3.23.2 installed on my machine as well.

I could not find any info on what the cmake error "Automatic include detection via cmake could not be executed. See log for details." means, I could also not find any relevant info about it in my *CMakeOutput.log*. What is going on?

Comment: A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="Automatic+include+detection+via+cmake+could+not+be+executed") for your error message returns no results so it seems likely to be something in your cmake file which is printing that message, please show a [mre]

Comment: You could search for the CMake installation directory, and then do a recursive search from there to find the term `Automatic include detection` in all files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, good advice, I am going to do that.

Comment: So it turns out that this issue is raised from the tool I was using, please see here for details:
https://github.com/PLCnext/PLCnext_CLI/blob/bc449510261ad25606454c58660657a7833f7128/src/PlcNext.Common/Project/RootEntityContentProvider.cs#L210
Thanks everybody for your help.